# GUI programs from Windows 10 Ubuntu shell

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am playing with the Ubuntu Shell on Windows 10. I created a code file in this environment and was trying to use sublime text editor to edit it.

I noticed that after I installed sublime text in Ubuntu shell and tried launch it, it shows me an error:

```
Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_pop from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_push from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_add from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_input_remove from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_keyval_to_unicode from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_region_get_rectangles from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_height from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_root_window from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_width from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_n_monitors from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_unicode_to_keyval from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_frame_extents from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_origin from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_get_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_invalidate_rect from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_set_cursor from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_window_move_resize from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_server_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_xatom_by_name_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gdk_x11_window_set_user_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accel_group_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_box_pack_start from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_set_active from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_clear from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_get from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_with_data from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_store from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_add from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_children from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_container_remove from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_add_button from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_run from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_dialog_set_default_response from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_dest_set from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_drag_finish from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_add_filter from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_filename from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_files from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_add_pattern from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_set_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_get_current_event_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_filter_keypress from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_context_set_client_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_im_multicontext_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_init from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_main_quit from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_attach_to_widget from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_bar_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_submenu from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_use_underline from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_popup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_append from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_shell_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_message_dialog_new_with_markup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_get_uris from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_selection_data_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_separator_menu_item_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_settings_get_default from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_show_uri from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_vbox_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_add_events from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_destroy from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_display from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_parent from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_screen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_get_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_grab_focus from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_hide from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_remove_accelerator from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_app_paintable from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_colormap from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_double_buffered from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_set_sensitive from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_widget_show_all from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_add_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_fullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_iconify from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_maximize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_move from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_present_with_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_remove_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_resize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_icon_list from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_default_size from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_keep_above from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_modal from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_position from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_title from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_transient_for from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_set_type_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_stick from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_window_unfullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load all required GTK functions
Unable to init px
```

I am wondering if the Ubuntu shell on Windows 10 doesn't support GUI programs? In this case, what's the recommended way to interact with the files in this environment besides using command line tools (i.e. code editing, viewing images, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You can install an X Server in Windows like [VCXserv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv).  This will allow you to run GUI based applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an X *Client* (the server needs to be installed in your Ubuntu environment as well) like [Keltari](https://superuser.com/users/94133/keltari) pointed out.

However, all files are accessible to you from Windows in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\lxss`.
You can simply edit them in Windows.